# Python plotly choropleth does not work with geoJSONs

Tags: python, plotly, gis, geojson, choropleth

I am trying to use plotly choropleth to draw the map, lets say for a random variable of num for each of the feature regions of the map in Italy. However, it does not work. below is the code that I use:

I have downloaded the GeoJson files for Italy from [here](https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/).

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
import json
pio.renderers.default='browser'

with open('it-all.geo.json') as f:
     geojson = json.load(f)

n_provinces = len(geojson['features'])

province_names = [geojson['features'][k]['properties']['name'] for k in range(n_provinces)]

randomlist = []
for i in range(0,110):
    n = random.randint(1,30)
    randomlist.append(n)

datadata = pd.DataFrame({'province':province_names, 'num':randomlist}) 

fig = px.choropleth(datadata, geojson=geojson, color="num",
                    locations="province", featureidkey="properties.name",
                    color_continuous_scale="Viridis")

fig.show()
```

What I am getting is a mixed shape map as below, can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong, thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I tried doing the same thing with data from my country and had the same issues. I think that this data might not be readable by plotly. If you look at the website's demos for their maps, there are several javascript scripts running in order to create the maps. It's possible that they've put their geojson into a custom format so that you have to use their javascript services in order to create a comprehensible map.

I later found a different set of data, and was able to easily create a chorpleth map with plotly using the exact same code that didn't work with the original data. Hopefully you found a different dataset that you could use. Oftentimes governments will provide open data about census areas, province/state borders, etc.